# Android Studio importing error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'collect'" (com.google.android.collect.Lists)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, guava

Here is what my build.gradle file looks like

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })



    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Can anyone figure out why it will not import com.google.android.collect.Lists?

Answer (score 0):

Guava does not have a class named `com.google.android.collect.Lists`. [The class is `com.google.common.collect.Lists`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html).